# Material: Navigation bar elevation or shadow

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, material-design

Setting the navigation bar color to something other than black only plays well with material design if you set it to transparent (or the same color as the window background) and the content is not scrollable.

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

If the navigation bar has another color or if the content is scrollable, the ink just gets cut off when reaching the bar like in the picture:

[image: Ink disapearing]

I would like to set an elevation on the navigation bar so that it casts a shadow and it becomes clear that it's another layer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to Google I/O Android talks, all shadows are generated by some light source, which provides shadows under elements, not above them. Then, Navigation Bar should have no visible shadow. [image]
Maybe, the only solution of your problem is to use additional drawable to imitate shadow.

Comment: Actually the shadows are also above. There's a directional light that casts most of the shadow under the elements, but there's also an ambient light that casts some shadow all around. See http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/environment.html#environment-light-shadow